# Impossible to round or truncate decimal Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in my Controller in Laravel 4. I try to round (or truncate) a decimal with 2 digits after comma, but it doesn't work.

I tried something like this :

```
round(888/100, 2);
```

Or :

```
floor(888*100)/100;
```

But I have 8.880000000000001 instead of 8.88.
Why?

(In this example I take this number but it can be an other number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this after rounding :

```
number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
// 2 = decimal places |  '.' = decimal seperator | ',' = thousand seperator
```

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!